# Git outputting "Error: Could not read SHA" on merge

Tags: git

I am working in my own branch.

When I merged the main branch into mine, I got the following:

```
git merge main
error: Could not read 7865ae...
error: Could not read d4a3e2...
error: Could not read 7865ae...
error: Could not read d4a3e2...
Fail to merge submodule xxx
Automatic merge failed: fix conflicts and then commit the result
```

I then resolved the conflict and pushed the result. What are these errors? Can I see what these sha codes are associated with?

If I do `git show` on the sha, I get `fatal: Bad object:`. How can I find out what this sha is? My repository is in GitHub, can I check there?